# Huawei data card not supporting New Macbook Pro OSX (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macbook, osx-mountain-lion, usb-3

I purchased Huawei data card and trying to connect with my new MacBook Pro (OSX- Mountain Lion) USB port 3.0 but unfortunately it does not support.
When I plugged in my macbook the power is flowing in data card due green light blinking twice in every 3 sec but no connection found or diver shown.

Please let me know how I have to use it. I got some suggestion for USB hub 2.0 but It does not make any sense and driver installation.
So please suggest proper direction to use it and provide link to install any driver.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Huawei E160 modem from Dodo (ISP) and have spent over an hour googling for help. I upgraded my mac-mini from Snow Leopard (where it worked OK) to mountain lion. It appears that no driver for ML has been written yet.  Since I have been running a "parallels" virtual machine (with WindowsXP) on my Mac-mini I am able to use windows drivers to connect my Huawei to the internet and use Windows IExplorer and webmail.
These VM software packages for the MAC (Parallels and Fusion) allow many network choices & I believe it is possible to get the MAC osx MLion to connect to the internet via the VM but I haven't found a simple way of doing this yet.  In Summary, if you purchased a VM software PKG. and installed a Windows OS like XP, you can get your modem to work AND use other Windows Apps. in an integrated environment.  So for the expenditure, you would get a lot of benefits besides just getting the Huawei modem to work. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for reply.. but i have a new macbook pro with osx ML purchased a month back, the data card works on SL, L, win 7.. even worked on usb3.0 on win 7.. but for usb3 on mac it is not even detecting.. can i get any drivers for that from mac drivers..? or any other solutions.. as i got the macbook to run only mac do not want virtually..